# How to setChecked ImageView on AndroidStudio

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working with the CC2640 of Texas Instruments and my custom app. Everything works perfectly, but I discovered a bug. In practice, from the app I can read the status of the inputs of my devices, so if they are free (green light) if they are busy (red light). At this time are set as Settogglebutton, but I do not want in the layout as a button but as images that change to the true/False value. How can I do that? This is my part of code:

```
                        if (intent.hasExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INPUT1)) {
                        setToggleButtonState(R.id.ingresso, intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INPUT1, 0));
                    } else if (intent.hasExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INPUT2)) {
                        setToggleButtonState(R.id.ingresso2, intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INPUT2, 0));
                    }

    private void setToggleButtonState(int id, int value) {
    if (id != -1) {
        final ToggleButton b = (ToggleButton) findViewById(id);
        if(value == 1){
            b.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            b.setChecked(false);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if i understood you correctly.
You want to change an ImageView resource according to the value?

```
private void setImageResource(int id, int value) {
if (id != -1) {
    final ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(id); // i assume you wont use this imageview anywhere else, you just want to change the resource.
    if(value == 1){
        myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.true);
    }
    else{
       myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.false);

    }
}
```

If you want the imageview to save the value, you could define it as an attribute and save it in the image tag.